# I'm getting this error /myproject/vendor/composer/../../App/Http/helpers.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I m `getting this`error`

> Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/goboot5e/public_html/myproject/vendor/composer/../../App/Http/helpers.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
>   in
>   /home/goboot5e/public_html/myproject/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
>   on line 66

when i have uploaded my project to the   `server(made live)`

**the things i have changed are(was working perfect on localhost):**

1. copied all `public` files into `server` root ie `public_html`
2. `database` configured through `.env` file
3. changed path in the index.php(now public_html/index.php)

Most importantly i have made a custom `helpers.php`  which is located in `App/Http/helpers.php`

my `composer.json` file `autoload` look like this

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],

        "files": [
            "App/Http/helpers.php"
        ], 
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: try this command: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: it works `absolutely fine on localhost` without a single `error`

Comment: @JigarShah, after executing `composer dump-autoload` only i have uploaded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. This problem occurs because laravel folder name is `app` but you use `App`. It works fine on localhost because windows OS is not case sensitive but linux is case sensitive. May be your PC is windows and server is linux

```
"files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
```

After changing run `composer dump-autoload` and upload your project again

Note : You can now upload only `composer folder (vendor\composer)` and `autoload.php (vendor\)`

Comment: Notice change `App` to `app`

Comment: Please read my answer again. I use app/Http/helpers.php instead of App/Http/helpers.php @MistyWingWEBGame

Comment: This trick helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the files names. your localhost's filesystem is case-insensitive, while the server is not.

double check that all names casing match with composer.json.

For example, if `helpers.php` is `Helpers.php` composer will not find the file.